# How to print confusion matrix of neuralnet predicted probabilities

Tags: r, neural-network, confusion-matrix

I need to convert the probabilities to true or false (> 0.5), and then print a confusion matrix.  I can't find an example of how to do this.

In my attempts, I'm also having difficulty referencing the transformed "Success" target, which is now "SuccessTRUE."

Success is Boolean, Comp is a factor (4 levels), the others are numeric.

```
require(neuralnet)
m <- model.matrix(~Success + Comp + Var2 + Var3 + Var4, data=Train3)
m1 <- model.matrix(~Success + Comp + Var2 + Var3 + Var4, data=Test3)
nn=neuralnet(SuccessTrue~Comp2 + Comp3 + Comp4 + Var2 + Var3 + Var4,data=m, hidden=4, act.fct = "logistic",linear.output = FALSE)
pred <- compute(nn,m1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.

```
> predicted.classes <- ifelse(pred$net.result > 0.5, "TRUE", "FALSE")  
> t <- table(predicted.classes,Test3$Success)  
> confusionMatrix(t)
```